# rails3 has_one association model creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails3, and I'm just trying to get one last thing to work before I call it a night. The situation is the following (please if the code is horrible, just let me know, still learning):

I want to log a dive. I might have a new location on that dive at which point I have to create a new Location, and then create the dive. A dive has_one location. A location has_many dives. Currently the foreign key is on dive as location_id.

How do I properly, in my dives_controller, generate the location, get the ID, and pass it on to my new dive? It would be nice to have the constructor of Location called, but if it doesn't work that way, then that's okay too.

My code is below:

```
class Dive < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :location

end

require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dive

    def initialize(location)
        @name = location[:name]
        @city = location[:city]
        @region = location[:region]
        @country = location[:country]

        url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+location[:city].sub(' ', '+')+"+"+location[:region].sub(' ', '+')+"+"+location[:country].sub(' ', '+')+"&sensor=false"
        resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
        googMapsResponse = JSON.parse(resp.body)

        @latitude = googMapsResponse["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
        @longitude = googMapsResponse["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    end

    def to_str
        "#{self.name}::#{self.city}::#{self.region}::#{self.country}"
    end
end

class DivesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @dive = Dive.new(params[:dive])

    if params[:location][:id] == "" then
        @location = create_location(params[:location])

        @dive.location_id = @location.id
    else
        @dive.location_id = params[:location][:id]
    end

    @dive.user_id = params[:user][:id]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your modelling needs some work and you should look at nested_attributes.

```
class Dive < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dives

    def to_str
        ...
    end
end

class DivesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @dive = Dive.new(params[:dive])

    if params[:location][:id] == "" then
        # Create new Location
        @location = Location.new(params[:location])
        url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
            @location[:city].sub(' ', '+') + "+" + 
        @location[:region].sub(' ', '+') + "+" + 
            @location[:country].sub(' ', '+') + "&sensor=false"
        resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
        googMapsResponse = JSON.parse(resp.body)

        @location.latitude  = googMapsResponse["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
        @location.longitude = googMapsResponse["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
        @location.save

        @dive.location = @location
    else
        @dive.location_id = params[:location][:id]
    end

    # This can be improved
    @dive.user_id = params[:user][:id]

    if @dive.save
        # do something
    else
        # do something else
    end
  end
end
```